# Get coordinates of selected area to use in image maps

Tags: plugin-development

I am developing a WordPress plugin that allows a user to insert image maps on the image from the WordPress default image editor. I want some JavaScript for it so that when user selects some area on the image it returns the coordinates of the selected area to use within the area tag.

Comment: "*I want some JavaScript for it so that when user selects some area on the image it returns the coordinates of the selected area*" - I don't see how this question is **WordPress**-related.

Comment: I am seeing a lot of questions lately that relate to JS, CSS or HTML but are under the guise of a faulty plugin or plugin development itself. Maybe time for a meta post (if there isn't already one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at this StackOverflow post - [Image Map Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323767/image-map-editor) - particularly the top answer's recommendation: [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/).

> imgAreaSelect is a jQuery plugin for selecting a rectangular area of
>   an image. It allows web developers to easily implement image cropping
>   functionality, as well as other user interface features, such as photo
>   notes (like those on Flickr).

Comment: +1 - and more if I could - for going to StackOverflow to find a related question *and* the right answer.